# What script should I use to remove apps not related to Eclipse development, without disturbing GUI functionality?

Tags: eclipse

I want to reduce the size of plain vanilla ubuntu desktop LTS 10.04.3,
as much as possible.
Purpose: use as eclipse development environment.
I don't want ubuntu server, I still need a GUI (run eclipse etc)

I tried script below, to remove apps not related to development :

> apt-get update; 
>   apt-get purge --assume-yes bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups compiz
>   compiz-core computer-janitor empathy empathy-common espeak espeak-data
>   evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server evolution-webcal
>   f-spot gwibber gwibber-service indicator-me indicator-messages brasero
>   pitivi rhythmbox gnomine quadrapassel gnome-sudoku aisleriot
>   gnome-mahjongg openoffice.org-* mono-2.0-gac python-ubuntuone
>   python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol
>   brasero-common cdparanoia esound-*;

but when I reboot, I drop into commandline login,
not GUI login.

What script should I use to remove apps not related to Eclipse development without disturbing GUI functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

To remove games safely try following command.

`sudo apt-get remove gnome-games-common`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm looking for a script that can trim my eclipse development .vmdk file down to a minimum, without having to build it from scratch.